# Does SSH only use a key named id_rsa?

Tags: ssh, ssh-keys

I created my own key named my_ssh_key_rsa, followign the steps illustrated here: http://www.linuxproblem.org/art_9.html Even though I added it correctly to the authorized_keys file on the remote machine, it still asks me for a password.

I also have an id_rsa default key. When I sat that up, everything went smoothly.

Does it mean that I need to use only id_rsa for ssh logins? I doubt it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use key with any name. But you should set it explicitly when making ssh connection.

The command line should look like:

```
ssh -i ~/.ssh/my_ssh_key_rsa user@host
```

Answer (score -1):

Your files are considered insecure to be used to complete a secure challenge step.
Change the properties of both files (client and server) to be read/write only by the owner:

```
chmod 600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys` #at server side
chmod 600 ~/.ssh/id_rsa` #at client side
```

Imediatly after that you will bypass the question about user and password in favor of a validated authorizer key.

Comment: You’re stating this as a fact, but really you’re just guessing, right? In fact, you’re almost certainly wrong about the `authorized_keys` file on the server, inasmuch as the question says that password-less login works with the id_rsa key. P.S. Why do your commands have backticks (\`) in them?